# How to switch between log4j configuration files at runtime with a condition

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have two different log4j.properties files. One is for production and the other one is for sandbox. Normally, application uses log4j.properties. But for sandbox version (by using a condition) I want that application should use a properties file which is created by me and named as sandbox-log4j.properties. Only difference between them is a log tracking line is added to sandbox version.

How could I make a switch between two files by using a conditin in a java file?

Comment: Why don't you just use a JVM option to override it? `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j-sandbox.properties`. Order of precedence is here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Yes I guess it is the soluiton that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. @Michael's suggestion on JVM helped me to handle the problem. I use Elastic Beanstalk and its JVM options field on Configuration provided to separate log4j.properties files. Setting JVM options to `-Dlog4j.configuration=sandbox-log4j.properties`is enough for solution.